# Javascript Date.parse returning NaN in blackberry browser

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

This is the code I am trying to run in blackberry simulator browser (OS V6.0).

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var d = Date.parse("Tue Oct 25 2011 18:33:17 GMT+0230");
var d1 = Date.parse("Tue Oct 25 2011 18:33:17");
document.write(d+"::::::"+d1);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever the GMT information is there is in the string I pass to `parse` method,it returns `NaN`,whereas it is returning a value if the GMT information is not there.But I cannot remove the GMT part from my string.

Any idea why this is failing?.Please note that it is happening in blackberry only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you can't remove GMT part?

Comment: I need that information for the subsequent action that I am performing with the parsed date.This string I am getting from the server side.If the GMT part is skipped out,the user's local time zone will be taken while parsing

Comment: Yes, but what I say is: why you cannot strip this GMT information, then parse the date and finally add the GMT part? If this a blackberry bug it's possible you cannot do anything else. Also you can try using datejs library, but I believe it uses system dates.

Comment: Good catch..Thanks for the pointer..If you can post it as an answer I will accept it for the record :) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can remove the GMT part:

```
var gmt = str.indexOf("GMT");
var newDate = str.substr(0,gmt-1)
```

then parse the data:

```
var d = Date.parse(newDate);
```

and finally, add the GTM part:

```
var offset_hour = str.substr(gmt+3, 3);
var offset_min = str.substr(gmt+6);
d.addMinutes(60 * offset_hour + offset_min);
```

The code is not tested and the last call corresponds to the [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) library.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create my own date string that BlackBerry was happy to parse. I did not add GMT.

```
// manually create date string because of BlackBerry parse method
var dateStr=dateObj.getDay()+' '+dateObj.getDate()+' 'dateObj.getMonth()+' '+dateObj.getFullYear()+' '+dateObj.getHours()+':'+dateObj.getMinutes()+':'+'00';
var mydate = Date.parse(dateStr); // works
```